# How to enable writing to C drive from Dos App?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I know it's a bad idea from security perspective. But it absolutely has to be done. 
Problem:
Windows 7 Home Premium x64, needs to run a DOS app that writes an output file to C:\ 
The app runs fine, but does not produce any error, and simply fails to write the file. I have tried runas and elevate - neither make any difference. I have given the user full permissions via the security tab to the c: drive - via the gui they can easily create a new RTF document in C:.

This is all because an existing accounting application that was running in Dos on XP was built by a now dead developer, the computer outlived him, and has been replaced by a Win7 box.

Comment: How are you running a DOS program on x64 Windows, which doesn't even _have_ NTVDM for DOS support? (Is it even a DOS program and not just a regular Windows console program?)

Comment: I am running it with compatability mode for XP SP3. The app certainly has the appearance of a DOS app, running in it's own window. I understand it is compiled xBase.

Comment: DOS apps don't have any specific appearance that would be different from Windows console apps... (for example, cmd.exe, the Command Prompt, is not a DOS app.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to figure out what files the program is trying to create and what errors it gets from the OS. If the program doesn't report any error, it might just be writing the file somewhere else.

You should see the actual process starting up, reading your accounting database, and creating the output file, before cmd.exe continues with other batch tasks. *(Note that the CreateFile syscall is also used for reading existing files, not just for creating new ones.)*

However, if it *really* is a DOS app, then it won't start at all, as NTVDM DOS emulation is not part of x64 Windows. In that case you would need to run a 32-bit Windows (e.g. in VirtualBox), or use tools such as DOSbox.

Comment: Thanks for that tool, very handy! Unfortunately it just gets to the operation of cmd.exe - CreateFile, the file name, and result= Name not found

Comment: That's odd – it should show up under the individual program's name, not under `cmd.exe` (which is merely the command shell), unless the saving is done by a batch script.

Comment: A batch script wraps the process that is supposed to create and save the file in some checking logic, then copies the created file to a network samba share where it can be used.

Comment: Right, so you should see the actual process starting up, reading your accounting database, and creating the output file, before cmd.exe continues with other batch tasks. However, if it _really_ is a DOS app, then it won't start at all as NTVDM DOS emulation is not part of x64 Windows.

Comment: Ok, so it really must be a fugly windows app then :)

I think I will have to load virtualbox, running XP, to get this thing going again.